# Why is my jQuery event not preventing the post?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that uses its own user database and authentication system rather than the standard account controller and aspnet auth system (There are no plans to change this). As part of this, I have a jQuery event that checks for the existence of a username before the form post to the server occurs to create a new user. When I place an event.preventDefault at the beginning of the .submit function, everything seems to work properly. However, I only want to prevent the post if the username already exists. In the example below, I never receive an alert and the post occurs Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ProcessApplication').submit(function (event)
        {                                             
            var un = encodeURIComponent($("input[name='form_email1']").val());
            var myurl = '/Home/IsUser/' + un;
            alert(myurl);
            $.ajax({
                url: myurl,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == '1') {                           
                        alert("This e-mail address is already registered. Please login, then resubmit your application.");
                        event.preventDefault(); // <-- I've tried both event.preventDefault(); and return false; here
                    }
                }
            });                
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `async: false` to your ajax settings.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Once I added this I moved my other logic out of the success handler and everything works now!

Answer (score 5):

You just need the `preventDefault()` earlier in your function...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ProcessApplication').submit(function (event) {                                             
        event.preventDefault(); // <-- Put it here
        var un = encodeURIComponent($("input[name='form_email1']").val());
        var myurl = '/Home/IsUser/' + un;
        alert(myurl);
        $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == '1') {                           
                    alert("This e-mail address is already registered. Please login, then resubmit your application.");
                }
            }
        });                
    });
});
```

Where you had it it was only being called after the ajax call was complete, which will happen way after a submit.

Comment: The event.preventDefault(); can be anywhere in the .submit() function (top or bottom), but not nested in the Ajax response function. Otherwise it will not try to prevent the default action, until after it has happened.

Comment: @badmin of course you're right.  It's just my coding style to put it immediately inside a function that's going to call it.  I have many quirks like this, like typing a destroy call for an object immediately after creating it, and then putting code in-between.  I'm rather anal about such things, but it serves me well :p